# gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish is never called

Tags: ios, swift, game-center

It seems that despite being able to setup the ViewController, allow myself to open it and view the leaderboards/achievements/etc, I'm unable to actually close the view controller using the "done" button."

Instead, I get absolutely no response nor do I get anything printed in the "gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish" function.

- Yes the delegate and whatnot is setup, otherwise I wouldn't be able to open it.

I just can't imagine what exactly is causing such an issue. Browsing the forums hasn't helped either unfortunately since every response simply makes note of needing the function which is required to even build the project.

```
func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(_ gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController) { 
    gameCenterViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil); }


func displayAchievements() {
    var game_center_view = GKGameCenterViewController();
    game_center_view = GKGameCenterViewController();
    game_center_view.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerState.achievements;
    game_center_view.gameCenterDelegate = self;
    self.present(game_center_view, animated: true, completion: nil); }
```

Edit: Displaying code concerned.

Edit: These methods were initially in a separate class to tidy up the code and keep GameCenter as a seperate thing. Moving the leaderboard and "didFinish" method to the main class appears to resolve all issues. Not the cleanest, but it works.

Comment: Post some code?

Comment: Edited to show the code this issue concerns, the displayAchievements method is simply displaying the GameCenter view controller, whereas the didFinish function is the default provided by XCode.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is from this code ... as this should work. But there is a separate issue that you are instantiating two completely different `GKGameCenterViewController` objects here. You should delete `game_center_view = GKGameCenterViewController();`.

Comment: How odd, completely missed that but thank you :)

Comment: @Valon What does self refer to? The scene? In my Game Center code I have to get the scene's view controller (self.view?.window?.rootViewController) and use that to present and dismiss the Game Center view controller.

Comment: Well in this case self simply refers to the ViewController :)

Essentially, there's only one view where anything to do with Game Center can happen (in my case anyway), and it seems to do the job just fine up until trying to remove the view of course

Comment: @Valon Your gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish line has an extra ( character after GKGameCenterViewController. By the way you don't need to  use semicolons to end statements in Swift.

Comment: Coming from Java, I don't think I'll ever get out of the habit of not using them ahah. (Plus it helps me personally distinguish where separate lines end). Not entirely sure why there's an extra ), doesn't seem to be one in xcode

Comment: @Valon You don't have an extra ) character. I don't know what your actual code looks like. But your listing here has the type of the function argument as GKGameCenterViewController() instead of GKGameCenterViewController. The types don't match. That's why your function to dismiss the view controller isn't being called.

Comment: @Valon Check the function.Because it happens in swift 3.0 if runs without error but it contains changed function syntax.

func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController!)
{
    gameCenterViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

check this syntax.

Comment: Thanks for this, however neither seem to be called :/
@Mark Szymczyk The issue here is that XCode only provides two options, "()" or ".self" which are to be added to the end, otherwise it throws errors.

Comment: @Valon Get rid of the ( character after GKGameCenterViewController. After GKGameCenterViewController there should be a ) character, like this: func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(_ gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController). At this point you should retype the gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish() function and make sure you type everything in correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure WHY that extra ( is there, as it isn't there in my actual code. And yet it still isn't closing the window.

This is the block as it stands:
func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(_ gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController) {
    print ("close: old");
    gameCenterViewController.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil);
}

Comment: @Valon Edit your question and remove the extra ( character so it doesn't throw other people off. Update your question with the code you put in your previous comment. Code is easier to read in a code block than in a comment.

Comment: @MarkSzymczyk Edited to show updated code.